# JQuery: Change container margin-left on window resize

Tags: jquery

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    updateContainer();
    $(window).resize(function() {
    updateContainer();
    });
});

function updateContainer() {
    var w = $(window).innerWidth();
    var img_head = $("#img_tag");
    var image_w = img_head.css("padding") + img_head.width();
    var cont = $("#image_container");
    if (w > 6*image_w) {
          var margin = (w - 6*image_w)/2;
          return cont.css('margin-left', margin + "px"); 
    } else if (w > 5*image_w) {
          var margin = (w - 5*image_w)/2;
          return cont.css('margin-left', margin + "px"); 
    } else if (w > 4*image_w) {
          var margin = (w - 4*image_w)/2;
          return cont.css('margin-left', margin + "px");    
    } else if (w > 3*image_w) {
          var margin = (w - 3*image_w)/2; 
          return cont.css('margin-left', margin + "px");    
    } else {
          var margin = (w - 2*image_w)/2; 
          return cont.css('margin-left', margin + "px"); 
    }
});
```

Relevant HTML

```
<div id="images">
<div id="image_container">
<img id="img_tag" src="image source etc.">
... 18 other images ... 
</div>
</div>
```

To provide a little more context, I have a list of images (all with the same dimensions and the same id, img_tag) in an image container and I am trying to change the left margin of the container when the window is resized. Currently this does not work at all. I am pretty new to Jquery and am not sure what the problem is. 
Thanks!

Comment: You're missing closing parentheses in multiple places in return statement. You should be checking the console for error.

Comment: That was a copy/paste error. Fixed.

Comment: You again changed the code what you had. Did you check now that it's working?

Comment: This isn't sufficient!! Provide `html` too if possible

Comment: The syntax errors that were pointed out were only in this version, i.e. it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy-paste this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    updateContainer();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        console.log('updating');
        updateContainer();
    });
});

function updateContainer() {
    var w = $(window).innerWidth();
    var img_head = $("#img_tag");
    var image_w = img_head.css("padding") + img_head.width();
    var cont = $("#image_container");
    if (w > 6*image_w) {
          var margin = (w - 6*image_w)/2;
          return cont.css('margin-left', margin + "px"); 
    } else if (w > 5*image_w) {
          var margin = (w - 5*image_w)/2;
          return cont.css('margin-left', margin + "px"); 
    } else if (w > 4*image_w) {
          var margin = (w - 4*image_w)/2;
          return cont.css('margin-left', margin + "px");    
    } else if (w > 3*image_w) {
          var margin = (w - 3*image_w)/2; 
          return cont.css('margin-left', margin + "px");    
    } else {
          var margin = (w - 2*image_w)/2; 
          return cont.css('margin-left', margin + "px"); 
    }
};
```

You still had syntax error. This one is running.
Whenever change is triggered, you'll see in the JS console log.
Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/4mxx513o/

Comment: What was the syntax error? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: In the last line you had an unexpected ')'